# How can I load date to mongodb using groovy in Jmeter

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter

```
Document document  = new Document("dateTime", "2019-03-01T01:11:52:44.089Z")
```

The value is stored as string datatype.
How to store dare in mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
def document = new com.mongodb.BasicDBObject("dateTime", new Date())
collection.insertOne(document)
```

More information:

- [MongoDB java-driver insert date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583306/mongodb-java-driver-insert-date)
- [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter)